# ファイルに書き込む文字列の変数が複数ある

Tags: python

ファイルに書き込む文字列の変数が複数あります。

```
x = "Hello World"
y = "google"
z = "deep learning is very popular now"
```

という変数が３つあります。このx・y・zをテキストファイルに書き込みたいです。

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.writelines(x)
f.writelines(y)
f.writelines(z)
f.close()
```

と書くべきなのでしょうか？それとも、

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.writelines(x)
f.close()

f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.writelines(y)
f.close()

f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.writelines(z)
f.close()
```

と書くべきなのでしょうか？どれもすっきりしたコードに感じないので、より良い書き方があればお願いします。
ちなみに、テキストファイルには

```
Hello World
google
deep learning is very popular now
```

のように一列ずつ書き込みたいです。

Comment: writelinesを使いたければ`f.writelines((x,y,z))`ですね。ただし改行は追加されません。`f=open(...); for l in (x,y,z): print(l, file=f)`が手軽で良いと思います。他の回答は全て文字列を結合してから書き出しているのでオススメしません。

Answer (score 3):

下のようにするのはどうでしょうか?

```
s = "\n".join([x, y, z]) # '\n'は改行コードを表しています
# x, y, zリストに入れて、改行コードで結合

f = open("text.txt", "w") # text.txt を書き込みモードで開く
f.write(s) # ファイルに書き込む 
f.close() # ファイルを閉じる
```

Comment: https://docs.python.jp/3/library/os.html によると、「テキストモードで開いたファイルに書き込む時には、 os.linesep を利用しないでください。すべてのプラットフォームで、単一の `'\n'` を使用してください。」だそうですよ。

Comment: 知らなかったです。
ありがとうございます!!
修正しました

Answer (score 1):

僕は1行で書ける処理は1行で書きたいので、pathlibモジュールを使います。
内部的にはwith openを使用しているので、自動的にファイルがclose()されます。
import文を足すと2行になってますが、気にしてはいけない。インデントしなくていいのがいいと思います。

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path("test.txt").write_text('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(x,y,z))
```

次の書き方のほうが短いので僕はよく使いますが、文字列連結のスピード及びメモリ効率が下がるので、沢山の文字列を連結するときは避けてください。質問例程度の文字列なら問題ないです。

```
pathlib.Path("test.txt").write_text(x+"\n"+y+"\n"+z+"\n")
```

次の書き方がスピードと効率と文字数の数が少ないので一番よいかもしれません。

```
pathlib.Path("test.txt").write_text("\n".join([x,y,z])+"\n")
```

"\n".joinという表現が違和感があるかもしれませんがこの表現はpythonでは標準的な表現です。
下記に文字列連結に関する公式wikiの情報(英語ですが)がありますのでご参考にしてください。
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation

追記として3回open closeする案はおそらくスピードが出ないやり方だと思います。基本的に文字列の組み立てはメモリで行いファイルとのやりとりは極力少なく(1回)にするのが好ましいです。

Answer (score 0):

どんなコードを「すっきり」と思うかは人それぞれですし、場合にもよると思いますが、
とりあえず、こんなコードはいかがでしょう?

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(f'{x}\n{y}\n{z}\n')
```

なお、Python 3.6 以上が必要です。